# Convert string to date object in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I want to convert below mentioned string to date object:

```
string_time = "06:13:19 25 March 2016 GMT  (Europe/Ireland)"

date_object = datetime.strptime(string_time, "%H:%M:%S %d %B %Y %Z")
```

The only thing i am not able to convert is (Europe/Ireland)

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dateutil.parser.parse`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> string_time = "06:13:19 25 March 2016 GMT  (Europe/Ireland)"
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(string_time.split('(')[0])
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 25, 6, 13, 19, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

---

**UPDATE**

to add an hour to the time and display it in the original format: Use [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) and add timezone part.

```
>>> import datetime                                                                
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> string_time = "06:13:19 25 March 2016 GMT  (Europe/Ireland)"
>>> tz_part = string_time.split(None, 4)[-1]
>>> d = dateutil.parser.parse(string_time.rsplit(None, 1)[0])
>>> d2 = d + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> d2.strftime('%H:%M:%S %d %B %Y ') + tz_part
'07:13:19 25 March 2016 GMT  (Europe/Ireland)'
```

Comment: above solution will give me time in this format 2016-03-25 06:13:19+00:00
Now again I have to add an hour to the time and display it in the above format.

Comment: @AnujKumar, I added another example that does reverse operation.